# EditText Padding not working

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-styles

I am writing a program in which i am using EditText and trying to apply padding, but it's not working.

**Styling EditText**

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_border</item>
   </style>
```

**Applying to EditText**

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPartyDate"
        style="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
        android:hint="@string/reservation_date"
        />
```

**AndroidStudio**

```
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
```

**Testing on Device**

```
    Android Version - 4.1.2
```

**drawable/edit_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#008f8471"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**Code:**

```
 editDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPartyDate);
```

Comment: can you please post your layout inflation code

Comment: make sure that you are not passing null as root parameter during layout inflation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your **edit_border.xml:**

From

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: both are same.. i have tried using this way as well

Comment: did you change the value of, from android:left="0dip" to android:left="2dip" for example.

Comment: glad for you and thank you but it's you who found the solution not me thank you again :). +1 for your anwser

Comment: bro place your answer, if you have noticed so this is what you highlighted me in EditText but i have made changes in XML file.. post for me

Answer (score 3):

Padding is rewrite in background resource (shape). Try to delete padding in *drawable/edit_border.xml* or add correct value for padding in this file. 
I tested. It's works)

Comment: i ticked your answer as useful

Comment: Also, you can use 
`<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditText</item>`
in AppTheme for the destination of style for all EditText's

Answer (score 2):

I have replaced **edit_border.xml:**

From

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
```